# how can i create alphanumeric user id on excel sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

The user id must have first three letters of the user first and last name as well as random number as shown below-

```
User id             Fname   Lname       Langu
AA_RoeDuT449        Roelof  DuToit       en
AA_IsmBha732        Ismail  Bhamjee      en
```

The user is must be like this.

Could some help using the formula that can give me this sort of ids? Thanks in heaps

Comment: The first bits are fine but the random number is a bit of a problem. Can you choose a random number yourself or did you want Excel to do this? Random numbers are typically volatile and will change every time you make an amend to the workbook, unless you generate them into a column with VBA. You can turn off volatile behaviour but then you might as well be assigning them manually.

Comment: Hi Jonno, i would say excel should generate the random numbers. I am not familiar with excel vba. is there anyway to modify  concatenate formula in excel. Please advise your suggested option on this...

Comment: The simplest would be to make an extra column called `RandomID` or similar and punch any 3 numbers in it. Not truly random though. Alternatively running a VBA script to populate a RandomID column as well as the UserID wouldn't be too difficult. You need something static to reference in your concatenate formula or it'll just keep regenerating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a VBA version. Formulas are a bad choice for this really as you'll need a fixed 'RandomID' stored somewhere. Also (In this case maybe not important), but if someones name changes (Marriage or similar) it would change their UserID. This solution gives a fixed output which won't change when you modify the workbook, and will only change if you manually change the cell. It also checks the UID it's setting is unique.

```
Public Sub GenerateUserIDs()
    'Get a quantity of rows by checking B2 for the last non empty cell. Add 1 because we have a header and
    'it won't be included
    NumRows = Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count + 1
    'Loop through all our rows, starting at 2
    For X = 2 To NumRows
        'Check each row, if column A is empty
        If IsEmpty(Range("A" & X)) Then
            Dim FName, LName, UID, ProposedUID, MaxNumberOfLoops, NumberOfLoops

            'If it is, get their first and last name
            FName = Range("B" & X).Value
            LName = Range("C" & X).Value

            'Set a maximum number of loops (If it loops more than this, quit, or we have an infinite loop
            'and Excel will crash)
            MaxNumberOfLoops = 400
            NumberOfLoops = 0

            'Set the UID without the random number
            UID = "AA_" & Left(FName, 3) & Left(LName, 3)
            'Keep looping until we find a UID that doesn't already exist
            Do
                'Add a loop count
                NumberOfLoops = NumberOfLoops + 1
                'Check if we've exceeded the loops
                If NumberOfLoops > MaxNumberOfLoops Then
                    'We have. Message box and quit!
                    MsgBox "Exceeded " & MaxNumberOfLoops
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                'Add the Random Number to our UID before testing if it exists
                ProposedUID = UID & RandomBetween(100, 999)
            Loop While CheckUIDExists(ProposedUID, NumRows)

            'We're out of the loop, so our UID is indeed unique. Set it in column A of the current row
            Range("A" & X).Value = ProposedUID
        End If
    'On to the next row!
    Next
End Sub

Function RandomBetween(Low As Long, High As Long)
    'Randomize the numbers (must be run to get a truly random number'
    Randomize
    'Get a number between our highest and lowest
    RandomBetween = Int((High - Low + 1) * Rnd + Low)
End Function

Function CheckUIDExists(ProposedUID, NumRows)
    'Again loop through all our rows
    For i = 2 To NumRows
        'Check if column A contains our proposed UID
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = ProposedUID Then
            'If it does, send True back, indicating it needs to run again
            CheckUIDExists = True
            'Quit early because we don't need to test any more rows
            Exit Function
        End If
    'On to the next row...
    Next i
    'We've done the entire loop, so it doesn't exist, return a False, indicating we can use that UID
    CheckUIDExists = False
End Function
```

As long as there is nothing in UserID, it will auto populate it for you

[image]

After run:

[image]

Comment: Hi Jonno, but by doing this does the user id contains AA_ also or they made like RoeDuT449. because end user must have AA_RoeDuT449....

Comment: Thank junno, i work on the proposed solution.....thank you so much, I might get back to you if i am stuck.

Comment: @shivomsaini Yes, I've just updated it, no formulas needed. As long as no UserID is specified, it automatically creates one.

Comment: @shivomsaini No extra column needed, just add all the details except their UserID and it'll populate them for you.

Comment: You could improve this to check if the resultant ID already exists - so as to not duplicate an existing ID - and regenerate a new random number and so forth until a unique ID is created.

Comment: How could i improve , yes it important that excel not making dups ids. I am sorry my knowledge is limited on excel. please clarify ......

Comment: @BigChris Yep, added, good point.

Comment: @shivomsaini Added it, I'll add some explanations as to what it does.

Comment: @shivomsaini Commented every line to assist you.

Comment: @Jonno thank you, i am working on it. I shall come back to you if needed. thanks vilen dank.

Comment: @Jonno thank you so much for the all effort that you put forward to make me understand, please can you tell me if i can save the macro on excel so i can use it often then creating the module everytime. I always have to create user id for different countries. therefore i though if i can save the macro, i tried to record it bit it did not work though. any suggestion?

Comment: @Jonno At bosch i wont be able to see the image(limited access to internet content) but will look at it at home. i ll also go through some basic and intermediate isual basic application on youtube. if you have a youtube channel so please let me know i will join......thanks a lot

Comment: @shivomsaini If you use it in just one workbook you can save it within that, otherwise you can save it to a workbook and run it as long as that workbook is open. See this screenshot where I am running a 'sharedworkbook' from another workbook called Book2. http://i.imgur.com/Mduld4Y.jpg

Comment: @Jonno thank you jonno, i figured out now. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `concatenate`, `left` and `randbetween` like this:

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(C2;3); LEFT(D2;3); RANDBETWEEN(100;999))
```

Comment: As stated above, this works fine unless you actually use the workbook. Every time you made an amend the random number will regenerate.

Comment: Right. A column with randomly generated numbers could be made (as large as the number of lines), copy them and paste them as values and eventually include these values in the concatenate as the last argument.

Comment: THANK YOU ALL OF YOU, i am really thankful for this and it worked exactly like our program used to make the ids. catalin big thanks to you and jonno i am thankful to you also for thinking of the possible solution. we always need guys like you, you guys are awsm

Comment: oh sorry,,,,i need to ask again...how can get AA_ combined with the user id- for example id are made like RoeDuT449 however i need them to be like AA_RoeDuT449 .....I am sorry i need to ask again

Comment: @shivomsaini It looks like you not understand the answer you were given. Look up those functions in the help.

Comment: @JanDoggen i ll look and try to understand, sorry